# how to compare string linq with sub query with another linq with sub query

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I Have 4 tables:

`Position` Table:

```
|     Position  |  PositionId  | 
|     driver    |     1        | 
|     clerk     |     2        |
```

`position Skill` table:

```
|  SkillId  |    skill     |     PositionId  |  
|     1     |   driving    |        1        |
|     2     |   drifting   |        1        |
```

`Worker` table:

```
|     Name     |    WorkerId | 
|     John     |     1       |
|     alex     |     2       |
```

`Worker skill` table:

```
|     skillId |    skill     |     WorkerId   |
|     1       |   driving    |        1       |
|     2       |   drifting   |        1       |
```

I `join` the `position` table with `position Skill` table
and `worker` table with `worker skill`

What I'm having trouble with is how can I compare the two `joined` tables to have a result of

for example:

I need to know who's `worker` have all the specific skills that the position have

Like:

I Select position with `positionId` of 1 and have the `skillname` of `driving` and `drifting`
I need to get the `Worker` with the same `skills` with `driving` and `drifting` also

so far i got this:

```
var PositionsWithSkills = (from a in db.Client_Customer_Position
                           where a.ID == position
                           select new
                           {
                               PositionID = a.ID,
                               RequiredSkills = (from b in db.Client_Customer_Position_Skills
                                                 where b.ClientCusPosId == a.ID
                                                 select b.SkillName)
                           }).ToList();

var WorkersWithSkills = (from x in db.Workers
                         select new
                         {
                             workerId = x.ID,
                             Skills = (from y in db.Worker_Skills
                                       where y.Worker_ID == x.ID
                                       select y.SkillName)
                         }).ToList();

var PositionWithSkilledWorkers = (from pos in PositionsWithSkills
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      PositionId = pos.PositionID,
                                      Workers = (from worker in WorkersWithSkills
                                                 where pos.RequiredSkills.All(skill => worker.Skills.Any(workerSkill => workerSkill == skill))
                                                 select worker.workerId)
                                  }).ToList();
```

the two `query` works well.. but the last query where i must compare the two query =.. i cant get the `worker id`
and can i turn this to a `stored proc`?

Comment: I think I have answered your question, and it should work efficiently since EntityFramework will create an Optimized SQL Query when it executes the link query.  This should execute faster than running three queries in the end and return the correct value.  What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if am wrong. What I got to know from your question is you want the workers list satisfying all the skills of the position you pass. If this is what you want you may try this:

```
 var workerWithallSkill = (from u in db.workerList join x in db.workerSkillList on    u.WorkerId equals x.WorkerId 
 where ((from y in db.workerSkillList where y.WorkerId == u.WorkerId select y).Count() == (from p in db.positionSkillList where p.PositionId == 1("pass your positionId here") select p).Count()) 
select u).ToList().Distinct();
```

or if you want to use lambda expression you can use this

```
var workerWithallSkill = (from u in workerList join x in workerSkillList on u.WorkerId equals x.WorkerId where (workerSkillList.Where(y=> y.WorkerId == u.WorkerId).Count() ==  positionSkillList.Where(p=>p.PositionId == 1).Count()) select u).ToList().Distinct();
```

For more understanding you can try the below code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IList<Position> positionList = new List<Position>() { 
                new Position(){ position="Driver", PositionId=1}
                ,new Position(){ position="clerk", PositionId=2}
              };


            IList<PositionSkill> positionSkillList = new List<PositionSkill>() {
                new PositionSkill(){ Skill = "driving",skillid = 1,PositionId = 1}
               ,new PositionSkill(){ Skill = "drifting",skillid = 2,PositionId = 1}
            };

            IList<Worker> workerList = new List<Worker>() {
             new Worker(){ name = "John",WorkerId = 1}
            ,new Worker(){ name = "alex",WorkerId = 2}
            };

            IList<WorkerSkill> workerSkillList = new List<WorkerSkill>(){
                new WorkerSkill(){Skill = "driving",skillid = 1,WorkerId = 2}
                , new WorkerSkill(){Skill = "drifting",skillid = 2,WorkerId = 2}
            };

            var workerWithallSkill = (from u in workerList join x in workerSkillList on u.WorkerId equals x.WorkerId where (workerSkillList.Where(y => y.WorkerId == u.WorkerId).Count() == positionSkillList.Where(p => p.PositionId == 1).Count()) select u).ToList().Distinct();

            foreach (var worker in workerWithallSkill)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(worker.name);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }


    public class Position
    {
        public string position { get; set; }
        public int PositionId { get; set; }
    }

    public class PositionSkill
    {
        public int skillid { get; set; }
        public string Skill { get; set; }
        public int PositionId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Worker
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int WorkerId { get; set; }
    }

    public class WorkerSkill
    {
        public int skillid { get; set; }
        public string Skill { get; set; }
        public int WorkerId { get; set; }
    }

}
```

if a worker has skills from different positions the above code will not work, if this is the scenario try the below code:

```
var WorkerPositionSkill = from p in db.positionSkillList join q in db.workerSkillList on p.skillid equals q.skillid select new { posSkill = p, workerSkill = q };

 var workerWithallSkill = (from u in db.workerList join x in db.workerSkillList on u.WorkerId equals x.WorkerId where (WorkerPositionSkill.Where(y => y.workerSkill.WorkerId == u.WorkerId && y.posSkill.PositionId == 1).Count() == db.positionSkillList.Where(p => p.PositionId == 1).Count()) select u).ToList().Distinct();
```

Comment: count !!??!? what if `position` with `PositionId = 1` has just `driving` skill and a worker has just `drifting` skill ?? with your query, any worker has just one skill, known as `skilled worker`

Comment: sorry I din get what you mean, "with your query, any worker has just one skill, known as skilled worker –" what my understanding is a position can have multiple skills and a worker will come for a position, so we want a worker which satisfy all the skills in that position. i would like to know where i am wrong. remark to your question "what if position with PositionId = 1 has just driving skill and a worker has just drifting skill ??" ---- then in which position you will add the drifting skill?

Comment: what you got is right, `position can have multiple skills and a worker will come for a position, so we want a worker which satisfy all the skills in that position`,and the question is `who's worker have all the specific skills that the position have`, but you compare just `count` of workers skills with `count` of `position skills` !.. , by your query if worker have same count of skills with a position skills return as worker who have all the position skills, but worker skills can be different with position skills, but they can have same count !!

Comment: Yeah I can under stand what you are saying, `when a worker has got skill both in   driver and clerk  for example if he knows document writing and drifting this code will not work , but if he is specific to  certain skills of one particular position alone for example driving alone, this code works. if there can be a chance of  a person having skills from two positions as mentioned before the table design has to be modified`

Comment: added a new code to help if a person have skills from both positions "driver" and "clerk"

Comment: sir the skillId of the position skill and workerskill is not the same
for example
PositionSkill table
positionskillId: 1 skill: driving
WorkerSkill table
workerskillId: 1 skill: drifting

Comment: Then you may please replace skillId with Skill for example in the last code replace  the " p.skillid equals q.skillid" with " p.Skill equals q.Skill" ,then the code will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var PositionsWithSkills = (from a in Positions select new {
      PositionID = a.PositionId,
      RequiredSkills = (from b in PositionSkills where b.PositionId == a.PositionId select b.skillId).ToList()
  }).ToList();

  var WorkersWithSkills = (from x in Workers select new {
      Name = x.Name,
      Skills = (from y in WorkerSkills where y.WorkerId == x.WorkerID select y.skillId).ToList()
  }).ToList();

  var PositionWithSkilledWorkers = (from pos in PositionsWithSkills select new {
      PositionId = pos.PositionID,
      Workers = (from worker in WorkersWithSkills where pos.RequiredSkills.All(skill => worker.Skills.Any(workerSkill => workerSkill == skill)) select worker.Name).ToList()
  }).ToList();
```

Comment: sir the skill table have a one is to many relationship with the position meaning for every position there maybe one or many skillId and its the same with the worker table and workerskill table..

Comment: modified answer to fit your exact requirement.

Comment: did you try this particular linq code? This was working for me with the sample data that you had shared.

Comment: sir do you use the skill id for the compare of the worker skill table and the position skill table...? what I need sir is the skillName itself to be compared not the ID.. is that possible? thanks

Comment: sir This is the error that i got...
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] ToList[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: sir the code that you suggest works but last query part of the code where the two query is being compared returned a null worker..

Comment: sir in this part where pos.RequiredSkills.All(skill => worker.Skills.Any(workerSkill => workerSkill == skill))
                                                   select worker.Name).ToList() where do you get the skill? and workerskill?

Answer (score 0):

This is highly unlikely to work with Linq To SQL because...its a huge steaming pile of #$%&. But this Linq query should given a sufficiently magical IQueryProvider give the right SQL. I've seen some very magical things come from Entity Framework.

```
var PositionsWithSkills = from a in db.Client_Customer_Position
                          where a.ID == position
                          select new
                          {
                               PositionID = a.ID,
                               RequiredSkills = (from b in db.Client_Customer_Position_Skills
                                                 where b.ClientCusPosId == a.ID
                                                 select b.SkillName)
                          };

var WorkersWithSkills =  from x in db.Workers
                         select new
                         {
                             workerId = x.ID,
                             Skills = (from y in db.Worker_Skills
                                       where y.Worker_ID == x.ID
                                       select y.SkillName)
                         };

var PositionWithSkilledWorkers = from pos in PositionsWithSkills
                                 from worker in WorkersWithSkills
                                 where pos.RequiredSkill.All(worker.Skills.Contains)
                                 group worker.Name by pos.PositionID;
```

PS please learn to use associations as opposed to join/where. If you are going to use join/where, you might as well just use SQL.

Comment: sir your suggestion is promising but when i try it on my project it just return this
"This method is not supported against a materialized query result."
how can i resolve this?

Comment: Yeah.. Don't use tolist where i told you NOT to.

Comment: another error appeared sir "Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025." do you encounter this type of error

Comment: My understanding is the EntityFramework will optimize the query when it compiles it to a SQL query.  It would seem faster to have one query in place of three, since you would have 3 round trips to get your answer when you break it up??  Wasn't sure what you mean by not using joins??

Comment: @user3294517 The point of ORMs is to abstract away the structure and relationships in your database. The logic of joining `Client_Customer_Position` with  `Client_Customer_Position_Skills` on the `ID` column and the `ClientCusPosId` column is common on all queries, yet, if you use join, you would repeat that everywhere. The point of `association`s is to encapsulate the `join` logic into your ORM layer. Also, your gratuitous usage of `.ToList()` will generate lots of database round trips. The creation of an `IQueryable` does not hit the database. You should search google for lazy evaluation.

Comment: @Aron I understand Eager vs Lazy evaluations, I give you points for your design, where you will make use of the data in various other queries.  My point is if you only need the data specified with no other look-ups being needed, this is still a valid efficient solution.  Good Talk.

Comment: @Aron And thanks for the reply back, what you say makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

i think, your database's tables have not been designed correctly...
you need a relation between `worker skill` and `position skill`, i think your tables must be desinged like this:

Skill table: SkillID, Skill

Position table: PositionID, Position

PositionSkill table: ID, SkillID, PositionID

Worker table: WorkerID, Name

WorkerSkill table: ID, SkillID, WorkerID

but by this way you designed your tables, if assume `skill` field (description of skills) are the same in `worker skill` and `position skill`, we can use this as a relation, and your query can be like this:

```
// skills of specific position
var PositionSkills = Context.PositionSkill.Where(u => u.PositionId == 1);

var WorkersWithSkills = Context.Worker
    .Join(Context.WorkerSkill,
          worker => worker.WorkerId,
          workerSkill => workerSkill.WorkerId,
          (worker, workerSkill) => new { worker, workerSkill })
    .GroupBy(u => u.worker)
    .Select(u => new
    {
       u.Key.WorkerId,
       u.Key.Name,
       Skills = u.Select(t => t.workerSkill.skill)
    });

var SkilledWorkers = WorkersWithSkills
    .Where(u => PositionSkills.All(t => u.Skills.Contains(t.skill)))
    .ToList();
```

if you wont change your database's tables, you can add a `join table` between `position skill` and `worker skill` like:

WorkerPositionSkill: PositionSkillID, WorkerSkillID

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **LinqPad program** that returns the result, { Worker = John, Position = Driver}.  If I understand your requirements you want to find a worker who satisfies the conditions where the worker has all the skills required for Position = 1, which is driving and drifting skills.  The query returns two rows the following [{worker = John, Position = Driver}, {worker = John, Position = Driver}].  I had to use distinct to display it once.  The reason for two rows is he satisfies both driving and drifting job skills. If the position required 4 skills in which the worker met, there would be 4 duplicate rows. The unique fixes that problem.  Hope this helps you along.

I created this solution in LinqPad, which is great tool with hundred's of very well documented linq query examples.

```
void Main()
{
    // Table Setup
    // ************
    var position = new List<Position>();
    position.Add(new Position { Id = 1, Name = "driver" });
    position.Add(new Position { Id = 2, Name = "clerk" });

    var positionSkill = new List<PositionSkill>();
    positionSkill.Add(new PositionSkill { Id = 1, Skill = "driving", PositionId = 1 });
    positionSkill.Add(new PositionSkill { Id = 2, Skill = "drifting", PositionId = 1 });

    var worker = new List<Worker>();
    worker.Add(new Worker { Id = 1, Name = "John" });
    worker.Add(new Worker { Id = 2, Name = "alex" });

    var workerSkill = new List<WorkerSkill>();
    workerSkill.Add(new WorkerSkill { Id = 1, Skill = "driving", WorkerId = 1 });
    workerSkill.Add(new WorkerSkill { Id = 2, Skill = "drifting", WorkerId = 1 });  

    // The Query
    // *********
    var positionValue = 1;

        var r = from p in position
                join ps in positionSkill on p.Id equals ps.PositionId
                join ws in workerSkill on ps.Skill equals ws.Skill
                join w in worker on ws.WorkerId equals w.Id
                where p.Id == positionValue
                select new {
                    PositionName = p.Name,
                    WorkerName = w.Name
                };

    // Get Distinct Names           
    r.Distinct().Dump();


}

// Define other methods and classes here
    public class Position
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }


    public class PositionSkill
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Skill { get; set; }
        public int PositionId { get; set; }

    }



    public class Worker
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }


    public class WorkerSkill
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Skill { get; set; }
        public int WorkerId { get; set; }

    }
```